# Leer archivo CSV y agregar los campos a un tableview JavaFX

Tags: csv, javafx

estoy intentando leer un archivo con formato CSV el cual tiene información de peliculas a través de un Filereader, agregar todos los elementos en una lista y luego mostrarlos en un Tableview en JavaFX. El problema es que no me ejecuta mi método.

`/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package act8;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Anton
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    Scene scene;
    Stage window;
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    FileChooser fs;

```
@FXML 
private TextField txtdatosd;
@FXML 
private TextField txtdatosr;
@FXML
private Button btnAbrirD;
@FXML
private Button btnAbrirR;
@FXML
private Button btncargard;
@FXML
private TableView tbldisponibles;

public void abrirD() throws IOException{
    File f=null;
    f=fs.showOpenDialog(window);
        if(f != null){
            txtdatosd.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }

}

public void leerArchivoCSVd() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
String csvFile = (txtdatosd.getText());
```

BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
//Se define separador ","
String cvsSplitBy = ",";
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] datos = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
        //Imprime datos.
       System.out.println(datos[0] + ", " + datos[1] + ", " + datos[2] + ", " + datos[3] + ", " + datos[4]);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
    }

```
public void escucha(){
    btnAbrirD.setOnAction(evt ->{try {
        abrirD();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

});

```
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    escucha();
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

Para leer cualquier archivo de texto plano te sugiero este código.

```
public Stream<String> leerAchivoExterno(String rutaArchivo) {
    Stream<String> lineas = null;

    try {
        lineas = Files.lines(Paths.get(rutaArchivo), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ArchivoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return lineas;
}
```

luego para agregarlo a una tabla (TableView), debes hacer varias cosas:

1. Primero crea una clase con la estructura de los campos de la tabla

Ejm: Formato para un tabla con una sola columna llamada descripcion

```
public class FormatoDescripcion {
private String descripcion;

public FormatoDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}
```

}

2. Luego debes inicializar la columna de la tabla y la tabla con esta clase

   ```
   @FXML
   private ObservableList<FormatoDescripcion> datos;
   @FXML
   private TableColumn<FormatoDescripcion, String> descripcion;    
   @FXML
   private TableView<FormatoDescripcion> tablaDescripcion;
   ```
3. Inicializar los valores

   ```
   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    datos = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    descripcion.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>  ("descripcion"));

   tablaDescripcion.setItems(datos);
      }
   ```
4. Agregar los valores que quieras dinamicamente. Este seria sobre la variable datos

ejm:

```
datos.add(new FormatoDescripcion("texto de interes"));
```